# SUM of data in assembly have error

Tags: assembly, sum

I have written this program to calculate sum of 2 hex numbers : (emu80x86)

```
data segment
DATA1  dw  9fffh,01h
ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

mov ax , 0

mov si , offset DATA1

mov cx , 02

again:
add ax , [si]
adc dx ,0
inc si
inc si
loop again

mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

but when I change DATA1  to `DATA1 DW aFFFH,0001H` it has an error said `cannot be evaluated DATA1 DW afffH,0001H`

I can't understand what has happened and I really got confused

Can anyone help me please. I know this is a very basic Question but I am new in assembly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hex number must always start with a number. So it should be

```
DATA1 DW 0aFFFH,0001H
```